# Swift Real-Time Multiplayer Online Game

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, real-time, multiplayer

everyone!

I'm in the process of making a real-time multiplayer game. Picture a castle game with two players, where each player has a castle to defend. The idea is that each player has their own iPad, and can shore up defenses, send out soldiers, and shoot projectiles using their own device.

Obviously, these changes should be reflected on both devices simultaneously (e.g. if player 1 shoots a projectile, it's motion should be animated on both screens at once).

My question is, what is the best way to accomplish that? Assume I am proficient at making single-player apps in Swift with SpriteKit, but know nothing whatsoever about multiplayer online programming. Thank you very much for your time!

P.S. Would it be useful to learn server-side swift?

P.P.S. I have been researching this topic for the past week, and haven't found what I need. Any help would be appreciated! Everyone who asks a question online seems to already know certain things that I do not.

Comment: I won't post an answer for this one since I've not really done game development but have read some of the areas with interest since keeping two clients in sync in as close to realtime as possible is one of those hard problems.

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking Valve have shared a tiny bit of how they approach the problem. This might be something that you want to read into lower level networking about.

Comment: Thanks, @marcus.ramsden! I'll read that article!

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of learning to do about multiplayer before you dive into making your own game

The idea is that you have a server, hosted on either a machine that you own or some web service like AWS

In that server, you have some sort of database, and some sort of game server running on a port.

There are 2 types of transport protocols, TCP and UDP. You can look those up, but for your proposed game TCP seems like what you need

You swift application connects to the server and sends all data do it about what the player does. The server sends a response with the current state of the game.

The server simulates all game logic. Think of it as the code you would actually write to make the game work in a single player game, except on a server so players can't hack the client and cheat

Think of the client as a dumb terminal just sending button clicks to the server and receiving updates about the game state. It should not handle any game logic other than rendering and prediction for fluidity

Go to the game development stack exchange for more info, or just do a google search on multiplayer video game programming

Swift probably isn't the best choice for your server. I personally use Netty in Java for my server side game code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth answer! These are things I really couldn't understand on my own (I'm sure it's clear that I don't even know what questions to ask). I have a couple of follow-up questions: There is something relatively new called server-side Swift (I found a free tutorial on it). Would that be what I would use to write the game logic and put it on a server for the dumb clients to connect to? I am taking Rob Percival's Web Development Course on Udemy, too. Would completing that help me understand more of what I have to do? Thanks again!

Comment: @retrovius Here is a good link on multiplayer networking : [link](https://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/)

Comment: @retrovius Web development and programming for multiplayer are two very different things. Web development focuses more on making websites, and integrating server side logic and databases with web pages and html & javascript. I think it would be good to start with that, as it will help you get a better understanding of networking in general, but it's not what you want for a game. Web development uses high level frameworks like asp.net or java EE to program, and doesn't have the configuration you need. You need to use a lower level networking framework so you have total control over development

Comment: server side swift seems like it is geared more towards websites rather than games

Comment: Thanks so much for that article! I'll check it out and get back to you. As for the server-side swift course, they seem to be using it to make multi-platform games, not websites. Games built with swift that run on both iOS and Android devices. Does that sound closer to what I should be learning?